# For which $q$ there exists a Steiner system $S(2, q, q^2)$?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, combinatorial-designs

I encountered the title question answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070531/building-a-3d-matrix-of-positive-integers). It is well-known (see, for instance [vdW, $\S$ 43]) when $q$ is a power of a prime number there exists a finite field of order $q$. In this case a [Steiner System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system) $S(2, q, q^2)$ [can be realized as a finite affine plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system#Finite_affine_planes). I guess that the answer for general case may be already known, so I googled for it, but failed to find it.

*References*

[vdW] B. L. van der Waerden, *Algebra* (Russian edition).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a notorious unsolved problem in combinatorics: are there any
$n$ other than prime powers for which an $S(2,n,n^2)$ (or equivalently
an $S(2,n+1,n^2+n+1)$) exists? The Bruck-Ryser-Chowla theorem implies
that if $n\equiv1$ or $2\pmod 4$ then if an $S(2,n,n^2)$ exists
then $n$ is a sum of two squares. This eliminates $n=6$.

The $n=10$ case was eliminated by Clement Lam, using a vast computer
search in c. 1989. Apart from these, little is known.