# Square board with $N\times N$ squares, at least $N(\sqrt N + {1\over 2})$ colored

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, contest-math, chessboard

In a square board made of $N\times N$ equal squares, at least $N(\sqrt N + {1\over 2})$ squares are colored (all other squares are, say, white). Prove that there are four colored squares that form a rectangle (the four colored squares are at the corners of some rectangle found on the board; for example, in a chess board, squares b2, b7, e2 and e7 form a rectangle while squares a1, a5, b1 and b6 do not).

I have tried to count all rectangles in the board, which is pretty easy, and sum the number of corners found in it, then to count to number a corners defined by coloured squares and make same comparison between the two but I fell short.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is well-known. I first met it when I was a schoolboy, learning the following problem from All-Soviet-Union mathematical competition from the year when I was born. :-)

> 208 a) Given a big square consisting of $7\times 7$ squares. You should mark the centres of $k$ points in such a way, that no quadruple of the marked points will be the vertices of a rectangle with the sides parallel to the sides of the given squares.
> What is the greatest k such that the problem has solution?
> b)    The same problem for $13\times 13$ square.

I scanned [its solution from [VE]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PACbj.gif) (in Russian). About the beginning of the millennium I met a similar problem related to graphs at [Erich Friedman's Math Magic](https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/1000.html).
Similarly to the scanned solution of the competition problem or to the proof of Proposition 1 [from my paper](https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/1000/4cycles.ps), we can find an upper bound on the maximal number $s=s(m,n)$ of squares which can be colored in a rectangular $m\times n$ board without forming rectangles. Namely, $s\le \frac 12(m+\sqrt{D})$, where $D=4mn^2-4mn+m^2$. In particular, if $D$ is a perfect square, that is $m=\frac{n(n-1)}{k(k-1)}$ for some natural $k$ then the upper bound proposed above becomes $s(m,n)\le km$. See also hardmath’s answer  to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571823/maximum-edges-in-a-square-free-graph) question about Füredi’s paper. But the board case is a bit different from the graph case and the known result do not need such subtle analysis as that done by Füredi. Namely, if there exists a [Steiner system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system) $S(2,k,n) $ then it yields $s(m,n)\ge km$, so in this case the inequality becomes an equality. This yield us an exact solution for a rectangular board $q^2\times (q^2+q)$ and a square board with a side $q^2+q+1$, where $q$ is a power of a prime number  [we still cannot construct respective Steiner systems for other $q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373801/for-which-q-there-exists-a-steiner-system-s2-q-q2) and  a [rectangular board $n\times n(n-1)/6$, where $n$ has a form $6q+1$ or $6q+3$ for some $q$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system#Steiner_triple_systems).

References

[VE] Vasil'ev N.B, Egorov A.A. *The problems of the All-Soviet-Union mathematical competitions*, Moscow.:Nauka, 1988 (in Russian).

Comment: Simple and elegant solution with a nice story added as a bonus. I just want to mention that the expression mentioned in the problem statement is slightly different from the solution explained in the book, but the difference is neglectable and could be eliminated with an additional approximation. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you remove any row and column, and there are at least 
$(N-1)(\sqrt{N-1}+1/2)$ coloured squares left, then there is a rectangle by induction.
So you can assume that fewer coloured squares remain when any row and column are removed;
 so each of the row and column you removed has at least a certain number of coloured squares, to make the grand total grow from below $(N-1)(\sqrt{N-1}+1/2)$ to at least $N(\sqrt{N}+1/2)$

Comment: This looks like an idea how to prove it by induction but it's far from the complete solution.

Comment: Perhaps you should have asked for the complete solution :)

Comment: Ok, I'm asking for the complete solution ;)

Comment: Ha ha ha ......

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are interested in a solution after almost 3 years but you can do it like this.

Imagine every row as a subset of $\{1,2,...n\}$, so we have $n$ subsets $R_1,...,R_n$ and let $r:= |R_1|+...+|R_n|$ be the number of colored squares, so $\boxed{r\geq n(\sqrt{n}+{1\over 2})}$. Now suppose the statment does not hold. Then each pair $\{i,j\}$ is contained in at most one row $R_k$ and every row $R_k$ contains ${r_k\choose 2}$ such a pairs (where $r_k=|R_k|)$. So we have $${r_1\choose 2}+{r_2\choose 2}+...+{r_n\choose 2}\leq {n\choose 2}$$

By Jensen inequality we have $${r_1\choose 2}+{r_2\choose 2}+...+{r_n\choose 2}\geq {{1\over n}r^2-r\over 2}$$ and thus we have $${{1\over n}r^2-r\over 2}\leq {n\choose 2}$$ Useing boxed relation we get a contradiction.

Comment: Anyway, are you working in a school?

Comment: A long time ago I was a professor of mechanics at our local university. After a decade or so I moved to IT for purely financial reasons. But I still consider mathematics to be the most beautiful science, a word of God, as Ramanujan would say. I do it for fun. My reputation is well above my mathematical knowledge but now, in my fifties, I am proud to say: I still learn math, I still love math.